# Why is SDL2 providing event values that are incorrect?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, visual-studio-2019

I'm using SDL2 v2.0.9-3, 64 bit, with VS2019 C++.  SDL_PollEvent returns events whose type field contains values that are incorrect.  The returned values are consistent, but wrong, ALWAYS!

I'm running code that worked correctly with older versions of the library and VC compilers.  I've tried building with VC2015 with the same result.  I've also tried using the VCPKG version and compiling SDL2 from scratch.  Always the same result.

Here's my code (with some debug output statements):

```
auto loop = true;
SDL_Event event;
long eventCounter = 0;

while (loop) {

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        std::wstringstream s;
        s << "Event " << eventCounter++ << ", Type: 0x" << hex << event.type << std::endl;
        OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str());

        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            loop = false;

        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    loop = false;
                    break;

                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    DoSomething();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

keydown returns 0x10002 (bigger value than SDL_LASTEVENT - should be 0x300) and keyup returns 0x3 (should be 0x301).  All other events are also consistent but wrong. Any clues?

Comment: Please post an MCVE so that people can easily test what you claim!

Comment: The `SDL_KEYUP` value suggests a relation to previous SDL-1.x stuff rather than SDL2 (3 was its value in 1.2.7 at least). You might be either compiling with or linking against the wrong thing, or possibly you didn't have a full rebuild after changing versions; Note that SDL1 and SDL2 are not compatible, but have a significant overlap in their API so in a hello-world style program it's easy to mix them up without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cubic!  Your response clued me in to the problem.  I had both SDL1 and SDL2 installed in vcpkg, so, even though I was including the correct header files, my program apparently was getting the SDL1 library linked in!  I removed SDL1 from vcpkg and the problem went away.

It would seem that they should be able to coexist in a package manager, but I guess not.  Lesson learned, don't have both SDL1 and SDL2 installed in vcpkg!